# Part-of-Speech tagging: what is the difference between known words and unknown words?

Tags: natural-language, model-evaluation, accuracy

I am trying to understand the result evaluation table (table 1) of this [paper](http://www.stefan-evert.de/PUB/GiesbrechtEvert2009_Tagging.pdf).

There are three different accuracies reported `overall`, `unknown words (UW)`, `known words (KW)`, and `percentage of unknown words (% unk.)`.

[image]

Are the `known words` the data that is used for training? And, are the `unknown words` the data that is used for testing and validation?

What is the overall accuracy? How is it computed?

What is the percentage of unknown words `% unk.`? Is it the percentage of the test set?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, if your question was answered, could you please accept the correct answer? It helps us both out, as well as people who have the same question in the future. If not, what can be clarified?

Answer (score 3):

**Known words** are words where the word has appeared with a POS tag in the training data. **Unknown words** are words that were not in the training data. In this work, a word has to be either known or unknown. (In semi-supervised learning, there are also **seen words** that appear in training but don’t have a tag.)

Overall accuracy is the percentage of all word tokens in the test set that received the correct tag. The next two columns (UW and KW) are the accuracies when only considering the unknown or known words, respectively.

The unk% is how many word tokens in the test set are unknown, as we defined it above.

---

As a fun aside: There’s a useful mathematical relationship between those quantities.

```
Overall = unk% * UW + (1 - unk%) * KW
```

That is, the overall accuracy is the weighted average of the unknown accuracy and the known accuracy. You can see with a calculator that this holds for the first row of their results.

Something fishy seems to happen with the second row, though. The overall accuracy is higher than for either known words or unknown words! Our mathematical relationship broke. This impossible result is likely an unfortunate typo on the authors’ part.